# Subplot drawn by auxiliary function experiences unexpected shift

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn

I'm trying to merge two plots in one:

1. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_iris.html
2. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_voting_decision_regions.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-voting-decision-regions-py

In the left plot I want to display the decision boundary with the hyperplane corresponding to the OVA classifiers and in the right plot I would like to show the decision probabilities.

This is the code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

def plot_hyperplane(c, color, fitted_model):
    """
    Plot the one-against-all classifiers for the given model.

    Parameters
    --------------

    c : index of the hyperplane to be plot
    color : color to be used when drawing the line
    fitted_model : the fitted model
    """
    xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
    ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()

    try:
        coef = fitted_model.coef_
        intercept = fitted_model.intercept_
    except:
        return

    def line(x0):
        return (-(x0 * coef[c, 0]) - intercept[c]) / coef[c, 1]

    plt.plot([xmin, xmax], [line(xmin), line(xmax)], ls="--", color=color, zorder=3)


def plot_decision_boundary(X, y, fitted_model, features, targets):
    """
    This function plots a model decision boundary as well as it tries to plot 
    the decision probabilities, if available.
    Requires a model fitted with two features only.

    Parameters
    --------------

    X : the data to learn
    y : the classification labels
    fitted_model : the fitted model
    """
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('Set3')
    prob = cmap
    colors = [cmap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, len(fitted_model.classes_))]

    plt.figure(figsize=(9.5, 5))
    for i, plot_type in enumerate(['Decision Boundary', 'Decision Probabilities']):
        plt.subplot(1, 2, i+1)

        mesh_step_size = 0.01  # step size in the mesh
        x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .1, X[:, 0].max() + .1
        y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .1, X[:, 1].max() + .1
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, mesh_step_size), np.arange(y_min, y_max, mesh_step_size))
        # First plot, predicted results using the given model
        if i == 0:
            Z = fitted_model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
            for h, color in zip(fitted_model.classes_, colors):
                plot_hyperplane(h, color, fitted_model) 
        # Second plot, predicted probabilities using the given model
        else:
            prob = 'RdYlBu_r'
            try:
                Z = fitted_model.predict_proba(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])[:, 1]
            except:
                plt.text(0.4, 0.5, 'Probabilities Unavailable', horizontalalignment='center', 
                         verticalalignment='center', transform=plt.gca().transAxes, fontsize=12)
                plt.axis('off')
                break
        Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
        # Display Z
        plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', cmap=prob, alpha=0.5, 
                   extent=(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max), origin='lower', zorder=1)
        # Plot the data points
        for i, color in zip(fitted_model.classes_, colors):
            idx = np.where(y == i)
            plt.scatter(X[idx, 0], X[idx, 1], facecolor=color, edgecolor='k', lw=1,
                        label=iris.target_names[i], cmap=cmap, alpha=0.8, zorder=2)
        plt.title(plot_type + '\n' + 
                  str(fitted_model).split('(')[0]+ ' Test Accuracy: ' + str(np.round(fitted_model.score(X, y), 5)))
        plt.xlabel(features[0])
        plt.ylabel(features[1])
        plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')   
    plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, bottom=0.08, wspace=0.02)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    X = iris.data[:, [0, 2]]
    y = iris.target

    scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

    clf1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4)
    clf2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=7)
    clf3 = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)
    clf4 = SGDClassifier(alpha=0.001, n_iter=100).fit(X, y)

    clf1.fit(X, y)
    clf2.fit(X, y)
    clf3.fit(X, y)
    clf4.fit(X, y)

    plot_decision_boundary(X, y, clf1, iris.feature_names, iris.target_names[[0, 2]])
    plot_decision_boundary(X, y, clf2, iris.feature_names, iris.target_names[[0, 2]])
    plot_decision_boundary(X, y, clf3, iris.feature_names, iris.target_names[[0, 2]])
    plot_decision_boundary(X, y, clf4, iris.feature_names, iris.target_names[[0, 2]])
```

And the results:

[image][image][image]

As can be seen, for the last example (`clf4` in the given code) I'm so far unable to plot the hyperplane in the wrong position. I wonder how to correct this. They should be translated to the correct range regarding the used features to fit the model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is the ends of dashed lines representing hyperplanes are not consistent with the final and expected `xlim` and `ylim`. A good thing about this case is that you already have `x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max` defined. So use that and fix `xlim` and `ylim` by applying the following 3 lines before plotting hyperplanes (specifically, add in front of your comment line `# First plot, predicted results using the given model`).

```
        ax = plt.gca()
        ax.set_xlim((x_min, x_max), auto=False)
        ax.set_ylim((y_min, y_max), auto=False)
```

Comment: When I try this I get and error and Python stops working: QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: `Unable to set geometry 1000x1069+9+38 on QWidgetWindow/'MainWindowClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  1000x1055+9+38 (frame: 9, 38, 9, 9, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 72x69, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).`

Comment: @pceccon It looks like this is a Qt problem, though I didn't see where the Qt came in in your OP. Sorry that I didn't take that into consideration. Also I'm not good at `pyqt`. To solve your problem, one option is to try the code without Qt, like in Jupyter notebook. That will help you nail down the cause of your "plot the hyperplane in the wrong position" problem. If the `xlim` and `ylim` are indeed the cause, you can then trouble shoot how to set `xlim` and `ylim` with Qt. Hopefully this may help...

Comment: I don't import pyqt explicitly. I'll try to figure it out the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @pceccon You're welcome. Sorry that I couldn't give you a full solution.